# Is there an android implementation of MPI?

Tags: java, android, mpi

Is there an android implementation of MPI? I used MPJ for just java. But it doesn't work with android(or maybe I'm doing something wrong while adding the lib).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remember, not all libraries written in Java have viable counterparts that work with Android. Android does not support the newest version of Java, and many libraries that have a Java implementations have to have a special Android implementation alongside for them to work properly.

Having said that, MPI (used in c) does not have a counter part in Android that I'm familiar with. Android, however, does use the Active Object Pattern. For your reference, you can find details here:

http://blog.coldflake.com/posts/Android-style-Message-Passing/

The basic idea is that messages sit in a MessageQueue, where a processor runs on a thread to pick up messages, called a Looper, and a Handler then tells who should process that message. All the synchronizing is handled implicitly within the MessageQueue so need to worry about writing a Lock class.

Be careful though, as opposed to just coding in Java, when you run threads in Android you must be certain that any work you do isn't blocking the main thread. There is something called runOnUIThread in Android, however I highly recommend against it.

Hopefully this helped, and have fun learning this Android Pattern!